# order of join in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a query which involves a `left join` followed by a `join`. I want to make sure the `left join` is done first. The `left join` comes before the `join` nin my query, is this enough? This is how the join looks like

```
select * from
  (select *....) A
left join
  (select *...) B
on A.a = B.a
left join
  C
on A.f = C.f
```

Comment: Could you share some code ? Otherwise it won't be easy to help you

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the JOIN in your code, only two LEFT JOIN statements.

However, if you have something like this:

```
select * from
  (select *....) A
left join
  (select *...) B
on A.a = B.a
join
  C
on A.f = C.f
```

and you want to make sure the LEFT JOIN is executed first, you can move this LEFT JOIN to a sub-query:

```
select * 
from (
  select * from ( 
    (select *....) A
    left join
    (select *...) B
    on A.a = B.a
  )
) D
join
  C
on D.f = C.f
```